# How can I convert "Sat Nov 06 05:48:16 +0000 2010" to '11-06-2010' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, date

How can I convert `"Sat Nov 06 05:48:16 +0000 2010"` to `'11-06-2010'` in Ruby? I've tried

```
Date.strptime("Sat Nov 06 05:48:16 +0000 2010", '%m-%d-%Y')
```

but I get this error:

```
ArgumentError (invalid date):
  /Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb:1688:in `new_by_frags'
  /Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb:1713:in `strptime'
```

I'm using ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036).

What am I doing wrong? Thank for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By my reading of the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html), your usage of `strptime` may be wrong. It seems like the second argument describes the format of the first argument, resulting in a very strict parse of the first argument.

So you can write in explicitly the format of your first argument into the second, and you should be okay.

A far easier solution might just be to use [`Date.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Time.html#now-method). Then, [`Date.strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Time.html#strftime-method) should give you exactly what you're looking for.

```
irb(main):001:0> require "date"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Date.new("Sat Nov 06 05:48:16 +0000 2010").strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
=> "11-06-2010"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'time'
Time.parse("Sat Nov 06 05:48:16 +0000 2010").strftime('%m-%d-%Y') # => "11-05-2010"
```